# How to add heading in this format

Tags: org-mode

I use org mode for many things including a Getting things done file and daily I am adding many headings, mostly in the format:

```
* TODO [#1] "Heading text here, to be typed in by me"
SCHEDULED: <2023-09-03 Sun .+1d>
```

I do use M-Ret or S-M-Ret to enter a new heading, but this does not add a priority, nor the SCHEDULED line.

I would like to add a menu item to automatically insert a heading in this format.

So far I have come up with this:

```
(defun myheading1 ()
  
  (interactive)       ; permit invocation in minibuffer

  (insert (format-time-string " \nSCHEDULED: <%Y-%m-%d .+1d>"))

  ) 


;; Add to toolbar:

(tool-bar-add-item "paste" 'myheading1
     'myheading1
      :help   "Insert heading"
      :label " Heading")
```

Which gives:

```
[Blank line]
SCHEDULED: <2023-09-16 .+1d>
```

Now I would like to use:

> (org-insert-todo-heading)

in my code to insert eg:

> ** TODO

in front of

> SCHEDULED: <2023-09-16 .+1d>

to get:

```
** TODO 
SCHEDULED: <2023-09-16 .+1d>
```

I tried:

```
(defun myheading1 ()
  
  (interactive)       ; permit invocation in minibuffer

  (org-insert-todo-heading)
  
  (insert (format-time-string "\nSCHEDULED: <%Y-%m-%d .+1d>"))

  ) 

;; Add to toolbar:
;; See other sections in this file for comments as to how to
;; Icons are in /usr/share/emacs/26.1/etc/images
(tool-bar-add-item "paste" 'myheading1
     'myheading1
      :help   "Insert heading"
      :label " Heading")
```

But I get error:
Wrong number of arguments

What am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: Please narrow the question - one, specific question per post. Thx.

Comment: I think you are looking for [org-capture](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html).

Comment: @Drew - I learned more about how to achieve what I want (using org-insert-todo-heading) and have made it one question :)

Comment: I still stand by my previous comment: you are looking for `org-capture`.

Comment: @NickD, thanks once again for your input. I looked at org-capture and TBH it seems complex and I dont understand it. It seems I have to specify a destination file, and execute a number of commands over and over. I would like to first try and get my code running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching thru many posts, I found the answer. Just had to add a "t" in:

```
  (org-insert-todo-heading t)
```

This code works:

```
(defun myheading1 ()
  
  (interactive)       ; permit invocation in minibuffer

  (org-insert-todo-heading t)
  
  (insert (format-time-string "[#1] \nSCHEDULED: <%Y-%m-%d %a .+1d>"))

  ) 

;; Add to toolbar:
;; See other sections in this file for comments as to how to
;; Icons are in /usr/share/emacs/26.1/etc/images
(tool-bar-add-item "paste" 'myheading1
     'myheading1
      :help   "Insert heading"
      :label " Heading")
```

And outputs, if there is no previous heading, eg:

```
* TODO [#1] 
SCHEDULED: <2023-09-16 Sat .+1d>
```

Answer (score 1):

Org mode has a built-in way to facilitate adding task entries like the ones you want: `org-capture`. It is a very flexible (and quick!) way to add a new task for later consideration and get back to whatever you were doing without breaking stride. It is also easy to start with (although admittedly you can get into some deep waters when trying to do complicated things).

All you have to do is add the following to your init file and restart Emacs:

```el
  ;; as recommended in the Activation section of the manual, we bind `org-capture' to `C-c c'
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'org-capture)

  ;; add an entry to `org-capture-templates' after `org-capture' has been loaded
  (with-eval-after-load 'org-capture
    (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
                 '("T" "add my TODO task"
                   entry (file+headline "~/org/tasks.org" "My tasks")
                   "* TODO [#A] %?\nSCHEDULED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a> .+1d>")))
```

Then `C-c c T` will bring up the filled-in template, with the cursor at the place indicated by `%?` in the template so you can fill in the description. Then press `C-c C-c` to finalize the capture and you are back where you were before the interruption, but with the new task safely squirreled away.

You have to create the file `~/org/tasks.org` and the heading `My tasks` in that file by hand before you can use the above  template, but after that you can keep adding tasks to your heart's content.

---

Notes:

- IMO, the best organization is to have a single file where all incoming tasks are squirreled away (like `~/orgh/tasks.org` above). During daily review, you can refile those tasks to the appropriate place (which will vary depending on many things - there is no way to cover all the possibilities).
- Things like SCHEDULED, priorities etc are best added during review, not during capture. Capture is meant to be fast and require virtually no thinking: it just makes sure that you won't forget something.

See the [Capture](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) and [Refiling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-Copy.html) sections in the manual. To see how one person does things with Org mode, I recommend Bernt Hansen's document [Org mode - Organize your life in plain text!](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html).

Comment: To the downvoter: I assume you did that because the OP specifically asked for a fix to his code. My answer however is not meant for the OP so much (he posted his own answer with the fix) but for people who stumble on this question without knowing that that there is a better answer to the original question (how to add a heading according to a template). Having them exposed to `org-capture` might be a useful counterbalance to the tendency to go write code to do it. Emacs is extensible, but that does not mean that every question requires an extension to be answered.

Comment: NickD thanks for taking the time to write your post about how to use Capture. If a destination file is required, this would not work for me, since I version files using the filename. Also, the solution I came up with works really well for me, and does not seem as complex as having to setup Capture. I will give your code a try though and see how it works.

Comment: Hi NickD. I dont think your answer works for me for a bunch of reasons. 1) It requires a destination file which I do not have or want 2) I disagree that it is best to later add eg SCHEDULED - why would I enter a task and know when to schedule it, but not schedule it, leave it till later, have to come back to it, and then schedule it. 3) Your way to enter the TODO needs Cc c T to initiate it, C-c C-c to finish it. My way needs a button click to initiate it and nothing to finish it. That saves hundreds of key presses per day.

Comment: 4) My way inherets the TODO type eg DEADLINE, from the previous heading, which I need. Your way does not - I would need to change from TODO to eg DEADLINE each time. For this reason, I dont think your post is an answer.

Comment: Re your: "that there is a better answer to the original question (how to add a heading according to a template)." - I disagree that this is an answer for the reason explained, much less a better one.

Comment: Re your: "Having them exposed to org-capture might be a useful counterbalance to the tendency to go write code to do it." Not sure what you mean, since you showed me the code to do it your way.

Comment: I think if you knew more about which processes and structures I use to organize things, you would say why your suggestion would not be a good one.

Comment: 5) Your way always uses a single star, ie top level heading, my answer inherits the number of stars from the previous heading.

Comment: In summary, your answer does not inherit either the TODO type or the heading level from the previous heading, which is what my code does (org-insert-todo-heading t) and what I need in this case. Therefore I dont think your suggestion is an answer.

Comment: Instead of trying to reply to all your points (some of which are things you wanted but never asked for; some of which are inaccurate - e.g. DEADLINE is not a TODO type; some where you have a point), let me say that I have nothing against you doing it any way you want. What I wanted to do was to make clear to *OTHERS* that your way is not the only way: this is not a conversation between you and me, that's one-and-done; it's a knowledge base that others might find useful in the future. Note that I did not downvote your answer: I accepted the fact that it works for you. As for the rest, ...

Comment: ... let's agree to disagree.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Hi NickD, you have been very helpful to me many times and I still greatly appreciate it - once I noticed you mentioned the down-vote, I tried to un-downvote it a couple of days ago, but the system would not let me. I guess there is a time limit on this.

Comment: As for your answer, it is an option for handling: Gettings things to do > How to capture thoughts for later processing. Please note I did not mention "How to capture thoughts for later processing" and this is not my use case for using this heading.

Comment: As to you mentioning that you did not downvote my answer, please feel free to go ahead and do that if you feel that is appropriate.

Comment: "What I wanted to do was to make clear to OTHERS that your way is not the only way: " Happy to have you point that out in this question. But you did not put it this way, you said it was a "better answer" and it is that which I do not agree with. Also I dont think this is a discussion between me and you. I think it is important for me to point out for the benefit of OTHERS why I think it has drawbacks.

Comment: That was after you downvoted the answer in the first place - and I qualified it: `there is a better answer to the original question (how to add a heading according to a template).` Most of the time, that is what people want to do: what *you* want to do I have no idea since you did not include any details in the question. In any case, enough time lost on both sides, so I am not going to continue this - as I said: let's agree to disagree.

Comment: - The answer to my question is to add "t" in the code, as I pointed out. Your post does not answer this.
- Ok then you could suggest code that achieves the same thing as the code I indicated in my post as I pointed out - but your code does not at all achieve that. 
- You say "what you want to do I have no idea" - so how could you possibly say you have a better answer???????? I dont need to explain what I want to with my code, to ask for help to resolve the error in my code above.
- Again, the suggestion you make is for capturing thoughts for later processing and that is *not* my use case.

Comment: - You say "how to add a heading according to a template" - nope, never asked to use a template. My specific question is still the same as now "how to add a heading in this format" - no mention of a template, yet you want to describe using a template
- I feel like you are telling me, who knows what he wants, is intelligent enough to decide what is an answer, that no, there is a better answer even though it is not, due to the reasons explained above.

Comment: You seem upset I downvoted your answer, when I have explained why it is not a answer.
I think you are hijacking my post. Please do not answer in future.